# Compose rational bezier curve

Tags: curve, bezier

i need compose rational bezier curve with different weight

[Curves](https://i.gyazo.com/25a328edc2155a8c8857d978018aba65.png)

At the moment I have **Curve1**

a,b,c,d,e,f,g  - controll points

q1,q2,q3,q4 - controll mid point (q1= b+c/2)

q3 e q4 - weighted rational curve

nice, but if two control point are close, it look like **Curve2**

they form two lines. But I want to have **Curve3**

all control points can change the weight

how can i get the curve 3?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a rational quadratic Bezier curve. To achieve the shape as Curve 3, you can

- add a control point a1 which is where you want the smooth join to start (it should lie on line(ab)).
- move control point c to where you want the smooth join to end (as indicated by b1 as shown in the following picture).

[image]